# c# mongodb read object field and show as null

Tags: c#, mongodb, null, read-data

Im currently working on a project with c# and mongodb. I'm trying to insert and read data.

The insert operation works as expected. But when I read, the value of a field is converted to null.

Data from database:

[image]

When I use c# to read data it transform it as follows:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

namespace Api.Models
{
    public class Correo : ICorreo
    {
        [BsonElement("direccion")]
        [JsonPropertyName("direccion")]
        public string Direccion { get; }  = null!;

        [BsonElement("activo")]
        [JsonPropertyName("activo")]
        public bool Activo { get; internal set; } = true;
        public Correo(string parDireccionCorreo)
        {
            this.Direccion = parDireccionCorreo;
        }
        public void DesactivaCorreo()
        {
            this.Activo = false;
        }
        public void ReactivaCorreo()
        {
            this.Activo = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And the model:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace Api.Models.Doctor
{
    public class Doctor
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string? Id { get; set; } = null!;

        ...

        [BsonElement("telefonos")]
        [JsonPropertyName("telefonos")]
        public List<Telefono>? Telefonos { get; internal set; } = new List<Telefono>();

        [BsonElement("correos")]
        [JsonPropertyName("correos")]
        public List<Correo>? Correos { get; internal set; } = new List<Correo>();

        [BsonElement("whatsapps")]
        [JsonPropertyName("whatsapps")]
        public List<Telefono>? WhatsApps { get; internal set; } = new List<Telefono>();
        
        ....
```

To read, I do the following:

```
public async Task<Doctor?> GetAsync(string id) =>
            await _doctorsCollection.Find(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Dont know what to do, because I have the same thing for WhatsApp array and it works...

here the model:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

namespace MMedicApi.Models
{
    public class Telefono : ITelefono
    {
        [BsonElement("numero")]
        [JsonPropertyName("numero")]
        public string Numero { get; } = null!;
        [BsonElement("activo")]
        [JsonPropertyName("activo")]
        public bool Activo { get; internal set; } = true;
        public Telefono(string numero)
        {
            this.Numero = numero;
        }
        public void DesactivaTelefono()
        {
            this.Activo = false;
        }
        public void ReactivaTelefono()
        {
            this.Activo = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Pleaseeee help!!! SOS

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it clearer what is `null`? You have a lot of fields here. Perhaps you could show your insert code too? How does the HTML you have provided relate to it?

Comment: Did you try add setter? `public string Direccion { get; set; }  = null!;`

Comment: Edited the question to display images, there is an icon for attaching images. Remove HTML as didn't see the question is related to it.

Comment: The workaround i took was to edit the full class and then update.
Thank y'all